# While installing the Cassandra getting the error

Tags: xcode, cassandra

Trying to installing the Cassandra in my local system getting the below error. Could you please solve or help on the error.

```
INFO  [main] 2021-04-22 19:23:16,662 CassandraDaemon.java:507 - JVM Arguments: [-ea, -javaagent:C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.10\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar, -Xms2G, -Xmx2G, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+UseParNewGC, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled, -XX:SurvivorRatio=8, -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml, -Djava.library.path=C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.10\lib\sigar-bin, -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199, -Dcassandra, -Dcassandra-foreground=yes, -Dcassandra.logdir=C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.10\logs, -Dcassandra.storagedir=C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.10\data]
WARN  [main] 2021-04-22 19:23:16,682 StartupChecks.java:169 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
WARN  [main] 2021-04-22 19:23:16,688 StartupChecks.java:220 - The JVM is not configured to stop on OutOfMemoryError which can cause data corruption. Use one of the following JVM options to configure the behavior on OutOfMemoryError:  -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError, or -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="<cmd args>;<cmd args>"
```

Answer (score 1):

These aren't errors - they are just warnings that some parameters aren't configured, and suggesting that you can configure some options.  Specifically you can ignore the second line (about JMX), but last line is more important - open `conf/jvm.options` and add the line with `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` option.

Comment: Thanks for you advice, I have added the same code (XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError) in conf/jvm.options and getting the same problem.

Comment: I think that you are missing - sign at beginning

Comment: I'm installing Cassandra 3.11.10 in the Windws 10 and I have the same problem. I added the line `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError`  in the `conf/jvm.options` file and the error persist. I needed to change the jna 4.2.2 to 4.3.0 first, beacuse another error before it. I don't know if it caused it.  Is there another way to fix it?